# How to make two numbers coincide

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

For the below plot:

```
m=1
q=5/2
K = Sqrt[4 m/(3 - q)]
ξ = (q - 1)^2/4 K^2
A = Pi/Sqrt[ξ]
Plot3D[1/A (1 + (q - 1) (Sqrt[ξ]) (x t))/(1 + ξ x^2), {x, 0, 20}, {t, 
0, 5000}, PlotLabel -> "q=5/4", BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, 
AxesLabel -> {Framed["x", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25], 
Framed["t", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25], 
Framed["ρ(x,t)", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25]}, 
LabelStyle -> Directive[16]]
```

[image]

how would it be possible to make the two zeros coincide and show as one so that it looks more clear?

Thank you!

Comment: Just a thought, you could define your `PlotRange` to exclude 0 from `z` axes. Although, there is probably a better solution

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Is there a specific way to do that?

Comment: Just define `PlotRange -> {{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax},{zmin,zmax}}`, you can use `Automatic` as an argument to let Mathematica decide what is `min` or `max`. For example, `PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic , {1,Automatic}}`. I think this should do it :s

Comment: @E.Doroskevic Well, it indeed did the trick! Thanks! :D

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example

**Description**

This can be achieved using `PlotRange -> {{xmin,xmax},{ymin,ymax},{zmin,zmax}}`, you can use `Automatic` as an argument to let Mathematica decide what is `min` or `ma`x. For example, `PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic , {1,Automatic}}`

**Code**

```
m = 1;
q = 5/2;
K = Sqrt[4 m/(3 - q)];
\[Xi] = (q - 1)^2/4 K^2;
A = Pi/Sqrt[\[Xi]];

Plot3D[
 1/A (1 + (q - 1) (Sqrt[\[Xi]]) (x t))/(1 + \[Xi] x^2),
 {x, 0, 20}, {t, 0, 5000},
 PlotLabel -> "q=5/4",
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic, {1, Automatic}},
 BaseStyle -> {FontSize -> 20}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Framed["x", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25], 
   Framed["t", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25], 
   Framed["\[Rho](x,t)", FrameStyle -> None, FrameMargins -> 25]}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[16]]
```

**Output**

[image: example]

**Reference**

[PlotRange](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotRange.html)